# Apply mlr3 pipes on group by basis

Tags: r, data-preprocessing, mlr3

I would like to know is it possible to apply `mlr3` Pipe processing on groupBy basis.

For example, from the `mlr3pipelines` documentation, we can scale predictors with following code:

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3pipelines)
task = tsk("iris")
pop = po("scalemaxabs")
pop$train(list(task))[[1]]$data()
```

But, is it possible to do scaling by group. For example, lets add month columns to iris data:

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3pipelines)
task = tsk("iris")
dt = task$data()
dt[, month := c(rep(1, 50), rep(2, 50), rep(3, 50))]
task = as_task_classif(dt, target = "Species", id = "iris")
```

Is it possible to scale predictors by month column? That is, we want to scale every month separately.
Using data.table, this is easy:

```
task$data()[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.vector(scale(x))), .SDcols = names(DT)[2:5], by = month]
```

but is it possible to do this inside the mlr3pipe graph?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no `PipeOp` that has exactly this functionality, you can write your own. You already solved the problem with `data.tables`. mlr3pipelines also uses data.tables internally, so it should be no problem to put your code into a `PipeOp`. The [mlr3book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/extending.html#extending-pipeops) explains how to write your own `PipeOp`.

Comment: Ok, I will check the docs and tried to implement scale group by. Should I make an PR if it will work as expected ?

Comment: is it possible to use the group role column in `PipeOpTaskPreproc` with `.train_dt` and `.predict_dt`? I was thinking to set monthid in above example to group role, and than cale by group. But not sure how to get group var in train_dt

Comment: Contributions are always welcome. If you use the group row role, resampling would also use this information. Maybe it is better to make this a parameter (`ParamUty`) of the `PipeOp`? Using `PipeOpTaskPreprocSimple` might be simpler.

Comment: I have just added example here on old issue: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3pipelines/issues/583